# Is a DELETE followed by an Insert faster than a Single MODIFY?

Tags: crud, abap, hana, opensql

I just found in a Class some Code, that wants to modify some rows in a Database. But instead of an Update or Modify, he used a Delete and an Insert. After asking him he told me, on SYBASE this was actually faster, but he isn't sure on HANA. I tried to test it myself.

Imagine you have this Sample Database:

```
@EndUserText.label : 'Datenbanktest'
@AbapCatalog.enhancement.category : #NOT_EXTENSIBLE
@AbapCatalog.tableCategory : #TRANSPARENT
@AbapCatalog.deliveryClass : #A
@AbapCatalog.dataMaintenance : #ALLOWED
define table zdb_test {
  key mandt : mandt not null;
  key col1  : char20 not null;
  key col2  : char20 not null;
  key col3  : char20 not null;
  col4      : char20 not null;

}
```

And this Sample Class to Test:

```
CLASS zcl_db_test DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC .

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_oo_adt_classrun.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.



CLASS zcl_db_test IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD if_oo_adt_classrun~main.
    DATA tab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF zdb_test.

    tab = VALUE #(
                ( mandt = sy-mandt col1 = '1' col2 = '2'  col3 = '3'  col4 = '4' )
                ( mandt = sy-mandt col1 = '5' col2 = '6'  col3 = '7'  col4 = '8' )
                ( mandt = sy-mandt col1 = '9' col2 = '10' col3 = '11' col4 = '12' )
    ).

    "Variant 1
    GET RUN TIME FIELD FINAL(t1).
    DELETE zdb_test FROM TABLE tab.
    INSERT zdb_test FROM TABLE tab.
    GET RUN TIME FIELD FINAL(t2).

    "Variant 2
    GET RUN TIME FIELD FINAL(t3).
    MODIFY zdb_test FROM TABLE tab.
    GET RUN TIME FIELD FINAL(t4).

    "Variant 3
    GET RUN TIME FIELD FINAL(t5).
    UPDATE zdb_test FROM TABLE tab.
    GET RUN TIME FIELD FINAL(t6).

    out->write( |Delete + Insert: { t2 - t1 NUMBER = ENVIRONMENT }µs| ).
    out->write( |Modify: { t4 - t3 NUMBER = ENVIRONMENT }µs| ).
    out->write( |Update: { t6 - t5 NUMBER = ENVIRONMENT }µs| ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

After running that 4 Times the Console output is like that:

```
Delete + Insert: 1.693µs
Modify: 753µs
Update: 1.122µs

Delete + Insert: 1.630µs
Modify: 878µs
Update: 739µs

Delete + Insert: 1.979µs
Modify: 813µs
Update: 770µs

Delete + Insert: 1.867µs
Modify: 781µs
Update: 1.097µs
```

Is my test flawed? Given its pretty simple. Or does it change if the Table has many rows in it? Or was it like that on SYBASE and on HANA a simple Update/Modify is the fastest? Sometimes Update is faster, sometimes Modify. I don't think there's a Performance Difference between those 2.

Edit:
Just tested it again with 1.000.000 Rows:

```
Delete + Insert: 5.785.950µs
Modify: 5.335.416µs
Update: 4.350.517µs

Delete + Insert: 10.169.629µs
Modify: 5.158.889µs
Update: 4.414.202µs

Delete + Insert: 10.066.633µs
Modify: 5.243.362µs
Update: 4.583.713µs

Delete + Insert: 10.232.670µs
Modify: 5.079.865µs
Update: 4.689.990µs
```

Seems like Update is always the fastest in my Example

Comment: The real question y'all should be asking yourself is "does it matter?"  Sub 2ms times are ridiculously fast for any database operation.

Comment: In any case, your tests seemed to have answered your own question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Happens way to often, that i answer my own Question without realising it. And the first test was with just 4 Rows, the Test with 1.000.000 Rows took a bit longer. And it was just a test case, we have tables with 500+ Million rows.

Comment: too much missing info; Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? table locking scheme? are indexes being updated? any triggers firing (eg, UPDATE trigger fires, but there are no INSERT/DELETE triggers)? is the DELETE/INSERT pair performed within a transaction? are (data/index) page splits an issue?

Comment: for HANA ... column store or row store table? INSERTs to column store tables are going to be (relatively) slower due to the need to perform individual 'inserts' for each column; the more columns you have the longer it takes to perform an INSERT; an update would be (relatively) faster especially if updating a few (of many) columns; a similar argument could be made for Sybase IQ (column) tables ... INSERTs are typically slower due to the need to perform separate 'insert' operations for each column

Comment: These results could varry even more, if you work with wider tables. If you do rows 10 characters long and 1000 characters long OR if you compare different infrastructures and have to account for ISP/routing parameters. A bulk of the operation is sending data between AS and DB. `DELETE`+`INSERT` is doing it twice. `MODIFY` is performing 2 operations internally, but you only set the data once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause it seems like it found my answer (at least on my Development System) and it might be interesting for others, i copied the Test results here to provide an Answer:
4 Rows:

```
Delete + Insert: 1.693µs
Modify: 753µs
Update: 1.122µs

Delete + Insert: 1.630µs
Modify: 878µs
Update: 739µs

Delete + Insert: 1.979µs
Modify: 813µs
Update: 770µs

Delete + Insert: 1.867µs
Modify: 781µs
Update: 1.097µs
```

With 1.000.000 Rows:

```
Delete + Insert: 5.785.950µs
Modify: 5.335.416µs
Update: 4.350.517µs

Delete + Insert: 10.169.629µs
Modify: 5.158.889µs
Update: 4.414.202µs

Delete + Insert: 10.066.633µs
Modify: 5.243.362µs
Update: 4.583.713µs

Delete + Insert: 10.232.670µs
Modify: 5.079.865µs
Update: 4.689.990µs
```

Seems like Update is always the fastest in my Example

Comment: I think you are pretty much measuring the abap virtual machine and the network latency between the abap system and hana. Delete + Insert is twice as slow as you have two roundtrips.

Comment: +1 for this comment. While both approaches (hopefully) yield the same resulting record, DELETE+INSERT are - at the very least - two commands that need to be processed instead of a single one. When updating a record, replacing all columns is not the common pattern. Instead, individual colunms of the a record get updated which leads to much more localised operations in the DB (e.g. constraint checking, index updates, etc.). If running two commands on SYBASE is quicker than a single command, it's worthwhile digging in and understanding the reason in detail.

Comment: @JonasWilms Could be. But thats the UseCase here. My colleague worte the Delete + Insert and told me its faster. I dont talk about HANA directly. He just said it was faster on Sybase, which sounded weird to me